# Google Big Query: How to alter data type from string to float?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have the following query and I would like to change the data type for the field "Reach" from string to Float.

The query that I am working on is the following:

```
SELECT 
  Account,
  Campaign_name,
   Date,
  Impressions,
  Cost__GBP_,
  Link_clicks,
  Ad_set_name,
  Ad_name,
  Reach,   
  Website_conversions   
From 'TableA'
```

And I am receiving the following  Issue: (google big query Could not convert the value to float. Row 8; Col 8)

I have tried to use to amend the query by doing : CAST (Reach AS Float64) As Reach , but it is not working.

Someone can help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: you should use `SAFE_CAST` as in below answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Account, Campaign_name, Date, Impressions, Cost__GBP_, Link_clicks, Ad_set_name, Ad_name, 
  SAFE_CAST(Reach AS FLOAT64) AS Reach, Website_conversions
From TableA
```

Comment: I have tried to use your suggested amend with SAFE_CAST but I am still receiving the following error:

 (google big query Could not convert value to float. Row 8; Col 8)

Comment: SAFE_CAST is identical to CAST, **except it returns NULL instead of raising an error**. so the fact that you still having error - tells me that problem potentially some-where else outside of info available in your question :o(

Comment: Yes I think I have an issue in my sourced data as the field Reach is now also containing some strings

Comment: if it contains string - the SAFE_CAST should return NULL and not raise any error!

Comment: I have rerun the data and is working now. There was an issue in detecting the right schema